# Novel about two sisters who died in car accidents; one of the sisters dreamt it would happen

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have read a novel about two sisters who died in a car accident, one sister died three and a half *hours* after the accident while the other sister died three and a half *days* after the accident. Before the accident one sister had a dream that they died in a car accident riding the red car and when she told her mother and sister they said it is just a dream.

Comment: Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, when did you read this? Was it new then?

Comment: I haven't read it but [_The New Normal_](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17074047-the-new-normal) by Ashley Little is about a girl who's sisters die in car accidents: _"They died from riding in cars with boys. Stupid, drunken boys."_